# ios - how to drag the crash report into the organizer?

Tags: ios

I am trying to debug a crash report which I need to "symbolicate" and I have never "symbolicated" before.

I came across some instructions to Drag/rop the crash report onto Organizer to have it symbolicated.

How do I do that? Do I save the crash report into a file and drop it somewhere? I am a bit confused. Could someone please explain the process?

Thanks!